# How to launch a Manipulate (or a function that uses Manipulate) via a Button

Tags: manipulate, dynamic, button

(Mathematica v13.3)

This seems to do nothing when you click the resulting Button:

```
Button["Launch", Manipulate[pt, {pt, {-1, -1}, {1, 1}}]]
```

Setting `Method->"Queued"` did not help.

How can a `Manipulate` be launched from a Button?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at the documentation for [`Button`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Button.html). After clicking the button, the expression in the second argument, named *action*, gets evaluated. But if you want the result of this evaluation to *appear* on the screen (in the notebook), you have to explicitly send it to the notebook. You can do this, for example, with `Print` (as shown many times in the documentation), or `CellPrint` or `Echo` ... or any other function that "interacts" with the notebook.

```
Button["Launch", Print[Manipulate[pt, {pt, {-1, -1}, {1, 1}}]]]
```

Comment: Could you please explain what exactly is the definition of "action" then in this context? i.e. why is `Print` which is a function is an "action" but "Manipulate" which is also a function is not an "action"? I.e. what are the semantics of the word "action" here? I looked at the page but see no definition of what constitute an action and what is not and it seems it is left for the user to interpret what this means?

Comment: @Nasser, I have expanded a bit my explanation. Long story short: clicking the button just evaluates second argument, it doesn't automatically send the output to the front-end.

Answer (score 3):

It seems Dynamics in general does not work directly inside a button (Manipulate is DynamicModule). Until someone figures why, here is a workaround.

[image]

```
Button["Launch", CreateDialog[{Manipulate[pt, {pt, {-1, -1}, {1, 1}}]}]]
```

Comment: `Button[..., Manipulate[...]]` is no different than `Button[..., 1 + 1]`. The 2nd argument to Button needs to be an explicit action.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another alternative, if you don't want to print or create a new window:

```
DynamicModule[{manipulate = ""},
     Column[{
        Button["Launch", 
          manipulate = Manipulate[pt, {pt, {-1, -1}, {1, 1}}]
        ],
        Dynamic[manipulate]
     }]
]
```

This shows how you would do this in principle using the `Dynamic Interactivity Language`. Depending on how complex your real use case will be, there might be need for some more tricks to make things work well...